# find words longer than 10 characters in sentences at sql column?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I find the longest words in the SQL column? For example, words longer than 10 characters?

TITLE column italic words have min 10 characters;

- *Non-homogeneous* Carbon *Fiberconcrete*
- Model for Poisson *Regression*
- *Accidental* Shot
- *Overtraining* in Swimming
- *Requirements* in Agile Chemical From Syngas

Comment: MySQL is not really suitable for this type of work.

Answer (score 1):

You might use :

```
 select length(t.col) as l_col, t.col
   from 
 (
   select 'Non-homogeneous Carbon Fiberconcrete' as col
   union all
   select 'Accidental Shot'
   union all
   select 'Overtraining in Swimming'
   union all
   select 'Requirements in Agile Chemical From Syngas'
  ) t
  order by l_col desc
  limit 1;

  L_COL  COL
  -----  ------------------------------------------
   42    Requirements in Agile Chemical From Syngas
```

Comment: How does this get *words* in the phrase longer than 10 letters?  How did it get an upvote?

Comment: @GordonLinoff do you mean that the part `where length(t.col) >= 10` is useless?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I thought of providing the both conditions by combining them with an AND : `longest words in the SQL column(i.e.TITLE)` AND `words longer than 10 characters`.

Comment: I think the OP wants to extract the italicized words from the `title` column.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for SQL Server.

```
select c.name as col
from sys.columns c
join sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
where t.name = 'your table name'
and len(c.name) > 10
```